# How to customize the default message composer in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, message

I need to customize the default message composer as at `To:` I need to diplay the recipient number and body contains an automatic message.
Can it possible to send this message without user interaction as he need not to be tap on to the send button.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) shows that you can programmatically set the `body` and the `recipients` of a text message.  It does not, however, expose an API to send the message automatically.  The framework requires user interaction.

It would be a *terrible* thing if an app could send a text message without user intervention.  If that were possible, then apps could fire off as many text messages as they wanted, to whomever they wanted, all while charges are getting applied to the user's cell phone bill.  That's a lawsuit waiting to happen.

So in a nutshell, you can pre-fill in some stuff, but the user will still have to tap the "Send" button.

Comment: One more doubt that can I customize the view of message composer is it possible to do?

Comment: @MonishKumar: There is no API for customizing the UI of the message composer.

Answer (score 0):

No. You may add recipients and put what you like in the body of the message, but the user will always see the message and will be able to modify it. The user has to choose to send it.

If you need to do this automatically, you'll need to implement enough of SMTP to be able to send messages on your own, without the help of the mail framework.